# How to change this iteration into a async function?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, asynchronous

This code isn't working probably, because the connection to mongo isn't established fast enough. So I thought that I have to change it to a asnyc function. But definetly doesn't know where to start. I'm new to Node and Mongo

| left |
| --- |
| Julian Graber 900 1 |
| windowsdemo 673 3 |
| laptopDemo 640 4 |
| IpadDemo 628 5 |

It should looks like that, but mongo updates it that every rank is the same digit.

```
// function for giving rank
function giveRank(arrayArg,resultArg){
  // declaring and initilising variables
    let rank = 1;
    prev_rank = rank;
    position = 0;
    // displaying the headers in the console
    console.log('\n-------OUR RESULTS------\n');
    console.log('Name | Mark | Position\n');
    // looping through the rank array
    for (i = 0; i < arrayArg.length ; i ++) {
            /*
            If it is the first index, then automatically the position becomes 1.
            */
            if(i == 0) {
                position = rank;
            Ranking.find({name: arrayArg[i]}).then((data) => {
                if(data){
                updateRank(bla, bla, bla)
                }else{
                newRank(bla,bla,bla);
                }
            });
            
            /*
            if the value contained in `[i]` is not equal to `[i-1]`, increment the `rank` value and assign it to `position`.
            The `prev_rank` is assigned the `rank` value.
            */
            } else if(arrayArg[i] != arrayArg[i-1]) {
            rank ++;
            position = rank;
            prev_rank = rank;
            Ranking.find({name: arrayArg[i]}).then((data) => {
                if(data){
                updateRank(bla, bla, bla)
                }else{
                newRank(bla,bla,bla);
                }
            });
            
            /*
            Otherwise, if the value contained in `[i]` is equal to `[i-1]`,
            assign the position the value stored in the `prev_rank` variable then increment the value stored in the `rank` variable.*/
            } else {
                position = prev_rank;
                rank ++;
                Ranking.find({name: arrayArg[i]}).then((data) => {
                if(data){
                updateRank(bla, bla, bla)
                }else{
                newRank(bla,bla,bla);
                }
            });
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: By "async function", you mean `async`/`await`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert a promise-chain-based asynchronous call into an async/await call, you only need to do a couple things:

1. Convert the parent function into an async function by using the `async` keyword, like so: `function myFunction (...) {}` turns into `async function myFunction (...) {}`
2. Use the await keyword in front of your function call, like so: `doStuff(...)` turns into `await doStuff(...)`
3. Convert the parameter to your first `.then()` callback to the return value of the async call, like so: `doStuff().then((data) => {})` turns into `let data = await doStuff()`
4. Move the body of the `.then()` callback below the assignment of the response, like so: `doStuff().then((data) => { console.log(data) })` turns into `let data = await doStuff(); console.log(data);`

So in your example, converting one of the functions would look like so:

```
async function giveRank(arrayArg,resultArg){
...
...
  if(i == 0) {
    position = rank;
    let data = await Ranking.find({name: arrayArg[i]})
    if(data){
      updateRank(bla, bla, bla)
    }else{
      newRank(bla,bla,bla);
    }
  }
...
...
}
```